# Generate service based on WSDL, that produces nearly same WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I need to create a SOAP webservice that will be consumed by a partnering company. The partnering company has supplied an example of a WSDL file for the service, as there are some naming conventions for methods and objects that must match theirs. It is a fairly simple webservice, with an `execute` method that takes an array of `NameValue` objects as input, and returns a `boolean`. This WSDL file is clearly for a SOAP webservice written in Java.

I have used `svcutil` to generate classes using their WSDL, to use for my own webservice, which is written in C# as a WCF service. The service is deployed, and I can call it using SOAPUI and get the expected results.

The partnering company however tells me that the WSDL for my webservice doesn't match the expected, and that my service cannot be called from their system. The error they are getting on their end is:

> The message with Action 'execute' cannot be processed at the receiver,
>   due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may
>   be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between
>   sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender
>   and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same
>   contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g.
>   Message, Transport, None).

When inspecting the WSDL produced by my WCF service, I see that some of the names are not the same as in their WSDL file. For example, the request message for the `execute` operation in their WSDL is called `request` but in my WSDL it is now called `IMyService_execute_InputMessage`.

How can I change my WCF service, so that the resulting WSDL matches that of the partnering company's WSDL?

Comment: Update: The partnering company has agreed to support a RESTful service instead, which has been implemented and works. However, I would still like to know if it is possible to generate classes for a WCF service, based on a WSDL file, that would produce the same WSDL file when deployed.